# Beta of portfolio containing stocks and risk free assets

Tags: college, university

(c) Tilly Tiepy has an equally weighted portfolio comprising 30 stocks and a risk free asset. The average beta of the stocks of 1.2. Tilly has half the value of her portfolio in treasury (exchequer) bills and half in the stocks.

What is the beta of Tilly’sportfolio?

Comment: Is this a homework problem?

Comment: Why would you ask if "(c) Tilly Tiepy" is a homework problem?  :->)